# Retrofit: 422 error

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm new in retrofit library.I have 422 internal server error, every time when i try to send POST request via Retrofit. What's wrong with my code ?

*MainActivity.java*

```
 public void setFruit()
{
    List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if(name.getText() != null)
    {
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

        fruit.setName(name.getText().toString());
        fruit.setColor(color.getText().toString());
        fruit.setWeight(weight.getText().toString());
        fruit.setDelicious(delicious);
        list.add(fruit);

        showPDialog();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GetData Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.100:8000/api/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<Fruit> call = service.insertFruit(list);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Fruit>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Fruit> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                printSuccess(""+response.code());
                hidePDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

*APIService.java*

```
public interface APIService {
@GET("fruits")
Call<Fruits> getFruitDetails();

@POST("fruits")
Call<Fruit> insertFruit(
        @Body
        List<Fruit> fruit
);}
```

Post request works well in Postman.

> **Updated:**

I found a solution to this. I tried this with a JsonObject rather than using a java object.

```
public void setFruit()
{

    if(name.getText() != null && color.getText() != null && weight.getText() != null)
    {

        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.addProperty("name",name.getText().toString());
        object.addProperty("color",color.getText().toString());
        object.addProperty("weight",weight.getText().toString());
        object.addProperty("delicious","1");

        Log.wtf("TAG",object.toString());

        showPDialog();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insert Data Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<JsonObject> call = service.insertFruit(object);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                printSuccess(""+response.message());
                hidePDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and this works well :). Thank you!

Comment: Well done for finding the solution yourself. Rather than including the answer in the question you are welcome to post it as a self-answer